# how to give space on writing inside input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a input tag and when I reach the input tag using tab key or click inside the input box I want that my cursor should start after leaving some space from the left border line. Following is my code

```
<input id="visiblevalue" type="text" name="value" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Value" value="" required="required"  onblur="if(this.value == ' ') this.placeholder = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Value'" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);"  />
```

Comment: Add some css-padding.

Comment: I tried can you please explain which padding should I work on left right

Comment: Obviously `padding-left`

Comment: I don't want my width of the box to change

Comment: guys I am new please can you explain text indent

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/riless/najrbq09/

Comment: @ankurjain I think padding is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many ways, we can do this. But, I think adding [CSS padding](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/css/paddingp2.php) is the best way.

The padding clears an area around the content (inside the border) of an element as shown in picture:

[image]

You can use `padding-left` property to leave some space from the left border line.

[All Solutions are implemented in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/najrbq09/7/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `padding-left` to the input, by using this in your CSS:

```
input {
   padding-left: 1em;
}
```

It isn't clear to me if you want this whitespace all the time or only when you're focused on that field. If you'd like the last option, you can fix that by using the [`:focus`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/) selector:

```
input:focus {
   padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try text-indent property. It specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.

```
input {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```